# How do I translate PostgreSQL OID using python

Tags: python, postgresql, types, database-schema, psycopg2

I am having bit of trouble with the psycopg2 Python module. I wrote a small code to extract some information from PostgreSQL table using psycopg2 module. I want to know the data type for each columns in the table:

```
import os, psycopg2, getpass, sys, string

userpass = getpass.getpass()

# Connect to the database
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=hostname dbname=db user=username password=%s" %  (userpass))
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM database.table;")

fieldTypes = [desc[1] for desc in cur.description]

print fieldTypes
```

When I execute this code, I get a list of integers (i.e. OIDs).  Is there a way to convert this into something that's more understandable (e.g. 'str','int','bool' and so forth).

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the "OID" to `text` by simply casting - provided the [OID (Object Identifier)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) is actually a [`regtype`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html#DATATYPE-OID-TABLE) (the OID-subtype for registered types) like you would get from the function [`pg_typeof()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE).

Postgres will normally display values of the data type `regtype` as `text` to the user. Example:

```
SELECT pg_typeof('2013-1-1'::date);
 pg_typeof
-----------
 date
```

While internally it is an OID:

```
SELECT pg_typeof('2013-1-1'::date)::oid;
 pg_typeof
-----------
      1082
```

If your client does not do the same you can force it with an explicit cast:

```
SELECT pg_typeof('2013-1-1'::date)::text;
SELECT 1082::regtype::text;
```

#### Get types of all columns from system catalog

It's unclear *how* you actually retrieve the types. Consider this query to get full information:

```
SELECT attname
     , atttypid::regtype AS base_type
     , format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS full_type
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'public.tbl'::regclass  -- your table name here
AND    attnum > 0
AND    NOT attisdropped
ORDER  BY attnum;

  attname   |          base_type          |         full_type
------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------
 age_id     | integer                     | integer
 age        | text                        | text
 ageabk     | character                   | character(2)
 foo        | boolean                     | boolean
 log_up     | timestamp without time zone | timestamp without time zone
```

Note that [**`format_type(..)`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) displays the type including modifiers.

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks for your reply.  I will definitely give that a try next week and post an update.  Thanks again for your help.